# Connection refused after SSL handshake

Tags: java, ssl, jax-ws, client-certificates

I'm trying to connect to a WCF server that needs a client cert. I've imported the client cert into a JKS file locally and provided the cert location to the JAXWS client using the -Djavax.net.ssl*** options. The SSL debug prints the below information before it finally gets a Connection refused exception. Apparently the handshake seems to successful but then a closeInternal(true) is called and then the exception. Any clues/ideas are much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
... no IV used for this cipher
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 17
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 68, 26, 22, 198, 55, 196, 10, 167, 6, 30, 206, 143 }
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 32
main, READ: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 17
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 32
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 233, 31, 138, 146, 138, 210, 137, 249, 81, 126, 169, 166 }
***
%% Cached client session: [Session-3, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 469
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 18
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:161)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:133)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:254)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:217)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:165)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:93)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
    at com.acs.echo.gen.EchoService.<init>(EchoService.java:46)
    at com.acs.echo.client.EchoClient.invokeWebService(EchoClient.java:43)
    at com.acs.echo.client.EchoClient.main(EchoClient.java:17)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSL handshake and TCP connection to the server are succeeding, but the retrieval of the WSDL is failing. It appears to be coming from a non-SSL host that is giving you 'connection refused', which means that nothing is listened at the port specified in the WSDL RL, or maybe an intervening firewall has vetoed the connect attempt.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My request is being rewritten by the server to forward to a 3rd party Netegrity where they are completely rewriting the request URL which I cannot access since I'm attempting to connect through a proxy/ip tables configuration. I've requested the server folks to not rewrite the entire URL but to change only the path of the URL. Is there any other solution to this? We have tried using SOCKS proxy but unfortunately, this web service client is part of a large web app and we cannot use the -DsocksHostProxy option because that will have an effect at the global app level.